# No generic RoutedEventHandler in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

Anybody knows the point of not having a generic RoutedEventHandler? We already have EventHandler<> which is great, why force devs to write their own custom routed event handlers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RoutedEventHandler` is equivalent to `EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>`, so `EventHandler<T>` is enough for routed events.